# How can I count the total width of many images in a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div element like this:

```
<div id="test">
    <img src="..."/>
    <img src="..."/>
    <img src="..."/>
    <img src="..."/>
</div>
```

What I want to do is first to make all the images having the same height, then calculate the sum of their new widths. I tried this :

```
window.onload = function() {
    var width = $(window).width(), totalwidth=0;
    $('#test img').height('200px');
    $("#test").each(function() {
        totalwidth += $("#test img").attr("width");
  });
  alert(totalwidth);
}
```

But the alert returns `NaN`. What should I do ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
 $("#test img").each(function() {
        totalwidth += $(this).width();
  });
```

Comment: use this instead of $(this)